# Apache server module installation: How do I resolve an apxs error?

Tags: apache, unix, module, ftp

Could you explain to me the meaning and possible fix(es) of the error below?

I am trying to install an Apache module for FTP
http://httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp/ftp/index.html. I am getting this error when try to build the source file using **apxs**:

```
apxs:Error: Sorry, cannot determine bootstrap symbol name.
apxs:Error: Please specify one with option `-n'.
```

Here is the full code in context:

```
$ apxs -iac mod_ftp.c
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc    -DDARWIN -
DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -no-cpp-precomp  -I/usr/include/apache2  -
I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1   -c -o mod_ftp.lo mod_ftp.c && touch 
mod_ftp.slo
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_ftp.la  -rpath 
/usr/libexec/apache2 -module -avoid-version    mod_ftp.lo
apxs:Error: Sorry, cannot determine bootstrap symbol name.
apxs:Error: Please specify one with option `-n'.
```

This is the first module I've ever attempted to Install on an Apache server, and I'm stumped. I can't seem to find an explanation of this. In particular, what is the **bootstrap symbol name** and how do I specify one with option -n?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

apxs cannot extract or misses a description for the module. Provide it with the `-n` flag before the source file name, and it should work, e.g.

```
apxs -iac -n mod_ftp mod_ftp.c
```

Worked for me in the case of mod_authnz_pam:

```
apxs -iac -n mod_authnz_pam mod_authnz_pam.c -lpam -Wall -pedantic
```

where the [author](https://github.com/adelton/mod_authnz_pam) omitted the -n flag in his installation howto, and I encountered your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the directions from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/mod_ftp/trunk/README-FTP ?

Since apxs appears to be in your path you should be able to just do:

```
./configure.apxs
make
make install
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. However, it doesn't appear to be actually installing the mod_ftp.so file anywhere - at least I can't find it anywhere. I tried the instructions found at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/dso.html (see Usage Summary > #4), and tried using **apxs**. However, I am using a downloaded version of MAMP as opposed to the Apache server that comes pre-installed with Mac OS X 10.5. When I run **apxs** it uses the one configured in `/usr/sbin/apxs` as opposed to my MAMP's apxs, which is installed at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs.

Comment: I'm thinking that mod_ftp.so is getting installed, but the system is installing it into usr/libexec/apache2 (the Apache server that comes built-in with Mac OS X 10.5), and I want it to install into /applications/mamp/library/modules, so that I can include with the LoadModule directive in the httpd.conf file of my **installed** Apache server. Should I just use the Apache server that came pre-installed with my OS??